# Why Spring Boot app doesn't consume application.yml file?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle

I have Intellij IDEA 2017.2.5 and few spring boot applications with gradle as a build tool.
For example in one them I have `application.yml` file with next content:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  application:
    name: config-service
management.security.enabled: false
server:
  port: 8888
```

But when I start it from the spring dashboard it doesn't consume the properties file and just uses default values:

[image]

Sometimes after rebuild it starts working, but it frustrates me.
Also when I start it from the terminal it works, so it's definitely a problem with Intellij IDEA or/and Gradle.
[image]

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I think that it is the IDE's problem. Because it works pretty good for me in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse).

Comment: I have the same problem with IDEA 2018.1. In a developer group of 3 all using the same version I am the only one with this problem. Suggestions anyone?